# Deducting Values from SQLite using Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a cursor that contains the results of a query which returns the a list of ingredient names and their corresponding measurements from an SQLite database.

I am trying to implement a function that will deduct these values from another table when a button is pressed.

I am having some trouble trying to implement this function using the cursor values. Can I just pass the cursor into the function or should I be putting the cursor into a list and then passing the list variables into the function?

Below is the code I have so far but if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

**Cursor**

```
   final Cursor ingredients = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
```

**getRecipeIngredients Function**

```
public Cursor getRecipesIngredients(int code)
{
    return db.rawQuery("select _id, ingredient_name, measurement from ingredients where recipe_code = " + code, null);

}
```

**Button code with function**

```
    Button cookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cookButton);
    cookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            while (ingredients.moveToNext())
            {
                String ingredient = ingredients.getString(0);
                String measurement = ingredients.getString(1);
                int i = Integer.parseInt(measurement);
                adapter.deductIngredient(ingredient, i);
            }
        }
    });
```

**SQL function to update table**

```
//deducting ingredients after cooking
public boolean deductIngredient(String ingredient, int measurement)
{
    db.rawQuery("update kitchen set kitchen.measurement = kitchen.measurement - "+measurement+" where kitchen.ingredient_name = "+ingredient, null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Either way would be possible.

Comment: Exactly, both should work well.

Comment: But how do I separate the cursor into a string and int for the `deductIngredient` function?

Comment: I updated the `while loop` in the button listener, is this an effective way or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Is your "measurement" stored as varchar or int?

Comment: Got it sorted, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching the values from the cursor and passing them instead of passing the cursor object itself.
Something like this:

```
Button cookButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cookButton);
cookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        while (ingredients.moveToNext())
        {
            String ingredient = ingredients.getString(ingredients.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));
            //If you are storing measurement as int
            int measurement = ingredients.getInt(ingredients.getColumnIndex("measurement"));
            //If you are storing measurement as varchar
            //int measurement = Integer.parseInt(ingredients.getString(ingredients.getColumnIndex("measurement")));
            adapter.deductIngredient(ingredient, measurement);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor holds the data for Ingredients Objects. The data in the cursor is organized in the column order of the table that the query was executed against. you can use index number of the column which contains the ingredient_name and measurment. Like this for example :

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredientList = new ArrayList<Ingredient>;
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
   Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient() ;

   ingredient.setName(cursor.getString([index of the column]));
   ingredient.setMeasurement(cursor.getInt([index of the column]);

   ingredientList.add(ingredient);
}
```